# Linux Kernel Module to interface with GPIO module on Beaglebone Black

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver, gpio, beagleboneblack

I write a Linux kernel module on Beaglebone Black to interface with GPIO module use its registers. A button connect with GPIO20, a LED connect with GPIO30 via a transistor 200 Ohm. I want when `insmod` kernel module then press button, LED ON and press again LED OFF, and so on. Following is my code for kernel module. My problem is when press button, LED not switch state.

```c
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

#define GPIO_ADDR_BASE              0X44E07000
#define ADDR_SIZE                   0X1000
#define GPIO_SETDATAOUT_OFFSET      0X194
#define GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT_OFFSET    0X190
#define GPIO_OE_OFFSET              0X134
#define GPIO_DATAIN_OFFSET          0X138

// enable IRQ
#define GPIO_IRQSTATUS_RAW_0_OFFSET 0X24
// enable interrupt
#define GPIO_IRQSTATUS_SET_0_OFFSET 0X34
// define intterupt type
#define GPIO_RISINGDETECT_OFFSET    0X148
// enable debounce feature
#define GPIO_DEBOUNCENABLE_OFFSET   0X150
// set debounce time
#define GPIO_DEBOUNCINGTIME_OFFSET  0X154


#define LED_VALUE_0                 ~(1 << 30)
#define LED_VALUE_1                 (1 << 30)
#define BUTTON_VALUE_0              ~(1 << 20)
#define BUTTON_VALUE_1              (1 << 20)

void __iomem *base_addr;

int init_module(void)
{
    uint32_t reg_data = 0;

    printk(KERN_EMERG "Hello");

    base_addr = ioremap(GPIO_ADDR_BASE, ADDR_SIZE);

    // CONFIG for LED
    /* write 0 to GPIO Pin 30 mean config this pin is output */
    writel_relaxed(LED_VALUE_0, base_addr + GPIO_OE_OFFSET);
    // at insert module time, led off
    writel_relaxed(LED_VALUE_1, base_addr + GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT_OFFSET);

    // CONFIG for BUTTON
    // config button pin is GPIO input
    writel_relaxed(BUTTON_VALUE_1, base_addr + GPIO_OE_OFFSET);
    // active IRQ
    writel_relaxed(0x1, base_addr + GPIO_IRQSTATUS_RAW_0_OFFSET);
    // enable interrupt
    writel_relaxed(0x1, base_addr + GPIO_IRQSTATUS_SET_0_OFFSET);
    // enable rising interrupt
    writel_relaxed(0x1, base_addr + GPIO_RISINGDETECT_OFFSET);
    // enable debounce feature
    writel_relaxed(1 << 20, base_addr + GPIO_DEBOUNCENABLE_OFFSET);
    // set debounce time
    writel_relaxed(0xFF, base_addr + GPIO_DEBOUNCINGTIME_OFFSET);

    while (1) {
        reg_data = readl_relaxed(base_addr + GPIO_DATAIN_OFFSET);

        if (reg_data == 1)
        {
            writel_relaxed(LED_VALUE_1, base_addr + GPIO_SETDATAOUT_OFFSET);
            mdelay(1000);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_EMERG "Goodbye");

    /* off led */
    writel_relaxed(LED_VALUE_1, base_addr + GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT_OFFSET);

    /* config default GPIO Pin is input
     * set Pin 30 to  default
     */
    writel_relaxed(LED_VALUE_1, base_addr + GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT_OFFSET);

}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Phu Luu An");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Hello world kernel module");
```

Comment: Why?! What's wrong with the existing driver?

Comment: I don't know. when I press button, it's not work: LED not ON

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve no C code is needed to be written. GPIO has a driver, buttons have a driver, and LED, connected to GPIO has a driver. What you need is to properly describe it in the Device Tree.

Comment: I want use code C to interface with GPIO module instead use sysfs

Comment: Then use it. We have IOCTLs for that. If your task is **not** for studying/learning, you are doing it completely wrong. Otherwise make clear the intention in your question.

Comment: Or if you are talking about in-kernel use, you have to check `gpiod_get()` and `led_classdev_register()` APIs.

Comment: Thanks about for your support.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have particular question I suggest to search over StackOverflow data base (actually Google can help with it) and I believe you will find tons of examples more or less close to your case.